# IndexOutOfBoundException when reading a file

Tags: java, sockets, exception, networking, inputstream

I am working on a TFTP server application. I managed to process a successful file transfer from server to client however the other way around is bugged.

Client instead of transmitting the entire file simply terminated whit compiler returning no errors. Debugger shows IOBE exception on the marked code referring that the array is out of range.

The whole transfer process goes like so:

1. Client transmits a file name and requested operation WRQ - Write Request
2. Server received the packet and determines the operation if WRQ is gives the new file appropriate name.
3. Server now starts executing receiveData() until it gets a packet < 512 indicationg EOT
4. Client keeps transferring data it read from the file.

Key code:

Client:

```
private void sendWRQ() throws Exception
{
    String rrq = "WRQ-" + data;
    outgoingData = rrq.getBytes();

    DatagramPacket output = new DatagramPacket(outgoingData, outgoingData.length, serverAddress, serverPort);
    clientSocket.send(output);
    //Thread.sleep(50);
    sendData();
}
byte outgoingData = new byte[512];
private void sendData() throws Exception
{
    DatagramPacket dataTransfer = new DatagramPacket(outgoingData, outgoingData.length, serverAddress, serverPort);
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(data));

    int x;
    while((x = fis.read(outgoingData,0,512)) != -1)  // << Debugged gives IOBE
    {
        dataTransfer.setLength(x);
        clientSocket.send(dataTransfer);
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }

    fis.close();
}
```

Server:

```
private void listen() throws Exception
{
    DatagramPacket incTransfer = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(incTransfer);

    clientAddress = incTransfer.getAddress();
    clientPort = incTransfer.getPort();

    String output = new String(incTransfer.getData());
    if(output.substring(0, 3).equals("RRQ"))
    {
        File test = new File(output.substring(4));
        responseData = output.substring(4);
        if(test.exists())
        {
            sendResponse("Y");
        } else {
            sendResponse("N");
        }
    } else if (output.substring(0, 3).equals("WRQ"))
    {
        File test = new File(output.substring(4));
        if(test.exists())
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat prefix = new SimpleDateFormat(date_format);
            String date = prefix.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

            responseData = date + output.substring(4);
            receiveData();
        } else {
            responseData = output.substring(4);
            receiveData();
        }
    } 
}


private void receiveData() throws Exception
{
    DatagramPacket receiveData = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(responseData));

    while(true)
    {
        serverSocket.receive(receiveData);
        if(receiveData.getLength() == 512)
        {
            fos.write(receiveData.getData());
        } else {
            fos.write(receiveData.getData(), receiveData.getOffset(), receiveData.getLength());
            break;
        }
    }
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: print `rrq.getBytes()` and see if it's correct. not sure if the `String` correctly handles special chars.

Comment: It's correct. problem not here this part is sent and received as it should be the problematic part is where i marked it in the code.

Comment: you don't provide the `outgoingData` definition, does it have enough space to hold 512 bytes?

Comment: What size is byte[] outgoingData ? I suggest you create a new byte[] to read into from the FileInputStream.

Comment: @Zaki you were correct. Seems a new byte[] array fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that can happen is if the offset or length parameters violate the constraints specified for `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)`; in this case probably the buffer isn't 512 bytes long. There's no need to specify the 2nd nd third parameters in this case, just omit them, then it becomes `read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)` internally, which can't be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the way this is coded, the 'outgoingData' field is:

1) Initialized to a length of 512

2) Then, in sendWRQ(), 'outgoingData' is re-initialized to whatever rrq.getBytes() sends back.

3) Then, in sendData(), 'outgoingData' is used as the intermediate buffer to read data from file and put it in the dataTransfer object.

However, since 'outgoingData' is re-initialized in step #2, the assumption in step #3 that 'outgoingData' is still 512 bytes in length is false.

So while EJP was correct in saying that using read(outgoingData, 0, outgoingData.length()) will work, there are some architecture issues that if you address, you'll clean up a lot of potential errors.

For instance:

WIth the code provided, there is seemingly no reason to have outgoingData declared at the class level and shared among two functions.  Depending on the rest of the app, this could end up being a Threading issue.
Perhaps byte[] buffer = rrq.getBytes(); in sendWRQ() and byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; in sendData().
Also, the 'data' parameter is at the class level.... for what reason?  Might be better able to be controlled if its a passed in parameter.

Lastly, I've had good luck using the do{} while() loop in network situations.  Ensures that the send() gets at least one chance to send the data AND it keeps the code a bit more readable.